# How do I install "colorls" on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I would like to install [colorls](https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls#) . It looks handy:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to follow [the installation instructions](https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls#installation). However, they don't seem to be made for Ubuntu.

First, because `gem` did not exist, I had to run `sudo apt install ruby-rubygems` .

Now, I experience this error when I try to install it:

```shell
$ gem install colorls
Fetching colorls-1.4.6.gem
...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/3.0.0 directory.
```

So I try using the `--user-install` flag:

```shell
$ gem install --user-install colorls
WARNING:  You don't have /home/flimm/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed unicode-display_width-2.4.2
Successfully installed rainbow-3.1.1
Successfully installed manpages-0.6.1
Successfully installed filesize-0.2.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing colorls:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/flimm/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/clocale-0.0.4/ext/clocale
/usr/bin/ruby3.0 -I /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby -r ./siteconf20230407-19626-voy41j.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/flimm/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/clocale-0.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/flimm/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/clocale-0.0.4/gem_make.out
```

How do I install (and uninstall) colorls on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install Ruby Gem with development headers:

   ```
   sudo apt install ruby-rubygems ruby-dev
   ```
2. Download and install a Nerd Font (needed in order to get the pretty icons to display properly). Open the downloaded archive file, and open each font file, and click the "Install" button:

   [image: Screeshot]
3. Set your terminal to use that font. (This step may not be needed)
4. Install `colorls`:

   ```
    $ gem install --user-install colorls
    WARNING:  You don't have /home/flimm/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
    ...
   ```
5. If the previous command warns you that you don't have the correct location in your path, modify `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent in your favourite shell) to add this line, which modifies your PATH:

   ```
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin"
   ```
6. To add tab completion, add this line to `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent in your favourite shell):

   ```
    source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh
   ```
7. Now restart your terminal. You should be able to run `colorls` now, with the new font taking effect.

To uninstall colorls, run `gem uninstall colorls` and remove the added lines in `~/.bashrc`. You might want to undo the installation of the dependencies as well.